# what is difference between passing by reference and address in array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

What is the difference between passing by reference and passing by address (using pointer) notation?

Is `int arr[] = int* arr` ??

I have added three samples of codes, I think the first 2 samples are passing by address and the last one is passing by reference.

```cpp
void fun(int *arr, unsigned int n) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
        printf("%d  ", arr[i]); 
} 
      
// Driver program 
int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}; 
    unsigned int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
    fun(arr, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>  

void fun(int arr[], unsigned int n)  
{  
    int i;  
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)  
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);  
}  
      
// Driver program  
int main()  
{  
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};  
    unsigned int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);  
    fun(arr, n);  
    return 0;  
}
```

```cpp
void scale_number(int (&num)[5]);
    
int main() {
    int number[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    scale_number(number);
    cout << number << endl;
    return 0;
}
            
void scale_number(int (&num)[5]) {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        num[i]=0;
}
```

Comment: First 2 examples are equivalent. Third one doesn't even use an array.

Comment: You also left out an important option, namely a reference to a native array, which is both feasible and potentially incredibly useful in C++. ex: `template<size_t N> void fun(int (&arr)[N])`

Comment: How to pass an array by pointer: `void func(int* arr, size_t arr_size) { ... };`.  How to pass an array by reference: `template <size_t N> void func(int (&arr)[N]) { ... }`.

Comment: sorry @AlgirdasPreidžius i edited the code

Comment: @WhozCraig i'm new to programming , i have never heard about template , i will try to study it.

Comment: @Eljay , so syntax is different , passing by reference is passing the size of array in [size] ,while in passing by address is passing size as another variable to function.
do i understand that correctly???

Comment: That sounds right.  The general purpose C++ way is to use `std::vector` instead of C style array, but sometimes there are specific reasons that a C style array is needed.

Comment: @Eljay i know that we use vector because it's dynamic so it can extend it's size in running time so it's better than array , is this correct??

Comment: It is correct for those reasons, plus also as an object it also knows about its own state such as how many items it contains.  So it has better encapsulation, rather than having to pass that information in through other means.

Comment: @Eljay thank you for that clarification

Comment: @logan_92 "_i edited the code_" Sure you did. Now the 3rd example [doesn't even compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iJznN0PYjbDxuQoe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is int arr[] = int* arr ??

In short:

- In a function parameter declaration: Yes.
- Otherwise: No.

Explanation:

- `int[]` is an array of unknown bound of integers.
- `int*` is a pointer to an integer.
- A function parameter is never an array. Any function parameter declared to be an array will be adjusted to be a pointer to element of such array. Therefore `int[]` is adjusted to be `int*`, but only when it is a function parameter.

---

> i think first 2 samples are passing by address and last one is passing by reference.

Yes. In first two example you pass pointer to an integer, and in the last example you pass a reference to an integer. There is no array in the last example however.

The main differences between pointer and reference are:

- Pointers are objects. References are not objects.
- Objects have storage (although sometimes it may be optimised away if not observed). It is unspecified whether references have storage - sometimes they do, other times they do not.
- There can be pointers-to- and arrays of objects. There cannot be pointers-to- nor arrays of references.
- Indirection through pointer is explicit (using one of the indirection operators). Indirection through reference is implicit (operations on a reference are performed on the referred object).
- A pointer can be default initialised, and it can point to null. Reference cannot (but reference can become invalid, just like a pointer can).

Comment: what does that mean ?? Indirection through pointer is explicit (using one of the indirection oeprators). Indirection through reference is implicit (operations on a reference are performed on the referred object).

Comment: @logan_92 It means what it says literally. What about it is unclear to you?

Comment: sorry for that , i'm new to programming ,you mean accessing the pointer and accessing the reference is different ??
to access pointer =>     *(ptr)
to access reference =>  we only use the name of reference ???

Comment: @logan_92 To be more correct: To access the *pointed object* rather than the pointer, you use the indirection operator as you show. And to access a referred object, you indeed do not use any operator, but simply use the reference itself.